# Check if a field exists in parameters select value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset which brings in distinct values of a column 'A' of table 'B' and these form the select values for a parameter 'Param_A'. In addition to this I have a main dataset which brings in data from table 'B' and contains the column 'A' as 'Field_A'.I do not want to alter the main dataset and hence I am using a tablix filter to filter out the result set of the main dataset. The tablix filter is supposed to be performing the below functionality :

*Expression:*
**Fields!Field_A.value in (Parameter!Param_A.value) or Fields!Field_A.value is NUll**

*Boolean Operator* :
"="

*Value*:
True

But I am unable to use the operator 'in'. It gives me an error.Could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'inStr' Operator which eliminated the possibility of using 'in' operator:

iif(InStr(Join(Parameters!Project.Value,","),Fields!project_name.value)>0,
true,false)

This helped me!